# How do I to hide ul menu?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am creating a menu using ul html, it works, but the problem is when I opened the website the menu is showing and I want it just show when mouse hover. I tried to change the css class but still can't do it works.

How to fix this ?

**Html**

```
 <div class="all-category">                            
                            <h3 class="cat-heading"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>CATEGORIAS</h3>
                            <ul class="main-category" >    
                                <li>Menu 1</li>
                                <li>Menu 2</li>                           
                            </ul><!--/ul-categorias-->
                        </div><!--/categorias-->
```

**CSS**

```
.header.sticky .all-category{}
.header.sticky .all-category h3{
    cursor:pointer; 
}
.header.sticky .all-category .main-category{
    opacity:0;
    visibility:hidden;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition:all 0.4s ease;
    transition:all 0.4s ease;
}
.header.sticky .all-category:hover .main-category{
    opacity:1;
    visibility:visible;
}
```

Below the image with what it's happening. The menu is showing when I open the site and I want that just show when the mouse hover

[image]

Comment: Check [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/dropdowns/) if you are using Bootstrap. And check out [hover selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) as well.

Comment: Plz, provide the complete required code, because the current code seems to work. [Check this](https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/YzpyYxN)

Answer (score 0):

CSS only solution would be

```
li {
   visibility: hidden;
}

ul:hover > li {
   visibility: visible;
}
```

We hide the all `li` elements as default. And display only the children of the `ul` that we hover over.

Hope this helps =)